# Windows server 2008 R2 Application error, and site is getting slow down

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, event-viewer

Im using windows server 2008 R2 and recently my site become very slow and when I checked the event viewer and found an error logged, following is the details of the error

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17965, time stamp: 0x506dcae6
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000bccd
Faulting process id: 0x1a1c
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce13bda0819289
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: a7c12f8b-7fc2-11e2-a5ff-002590529142
```

Please help me to find how this error occurs and how to solve this issue.

Comment: The information you posted doesn't tell us very much.

Comment: Im not familiar with the server things, if you can say what kind of information are needed for more clarity that would be helpful.